# Prove if a polar function involves only the rational numbers and sin, cos, tan functions, it can be written in rectangular form.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, plane-curves

Prove if a function only have including the rational numbers and sin, cos, tan function and $r$, you always could write it in rectangular form. Ex. For $r=2/(2+2\cos\theta)$ it could be represent in rectangular form. Rectangular form is where the $r$ in the original function is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and you could create a function in terms of $x$ and $y$ that is $=0$ that is refer to the original function

Also, another question would be: What other trig function could involved in a function if it could be represent in rectangular form.

is there a complete answer for this question?

Comment: Could you define rectangular form?

Comment: @Alex: Conversion from polar to rectangular coordinates.

Comment: My tentative translation : "If a curve is described by a polar equation $r = f(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$ (with $f \in \mathbb{Q}(X)$), can we define the same curve using a cartesian equation?"

Comment: What about something like: $r(\theta)=\sin(\tan(\theta))$? (that is, are you explicitly disallowing function composition?)

Comment: @deoxygerbe - yes, no composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\cos(\theta) = x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\sin(\theta) = y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\tan(\theta) = y/x$ in the polar equation.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, that is my meaning